# Fade in arbitrary number of text lines sequentially with jquery queue

Tags: javascript, jquery, queue, transition, sequential

This gets pretty specific but I'd like to be able to fade in an arbitrary number of children sequentially and with delayed timing using jquery queue (though I'm open to other methods).  Here is what I have working already.

This is the basic html block I'm working with

```
<header>
  <p class="copy">Thing one</p>
  <p class="copy">Thing two</p>
  <p class="copy">Cat in the Hat</p>
</header>
```

This current jquery works, but it feels hacky to me in that I need to know in advance how many nodes to expect.

```
var $screenHeader = $('header');
$screenHeader.queue(function () {
  $screenHeader.find('.copy:nth-child(1)').addClass('visible');
  $(this).dequeue();
})
.delay(1500)
.queue(function () {
  $screenHeader.find('.copy:nth-child(2)').addClass('visible');
  $(this).dequeue();
})
.delay(1500)
.queue(function () {
  $screenHeader.find('.copy:nth-child(3)').addClass('visible');
  $(this).dequeue();
})
.delay(1500);
```

I would love it if something like this worked

```
for (var i = 1; i < $screenHeader.children().length+1; i++) {          
  $screenHeader.queue(function () {
    $screenHeader.find('.copy:nth-child('+i+')').addClass('visible');
    $screenHeader.dequeue();
  }).delay(1500);
}
```

or better yet

```
$screenHeader.children().each(function (i) {
  $screenHeader.queue(function () {
    $screenHeader.find('.copy:nth-child('+i+')').addClass('visible');
    $screenHeader.dequeue();
  }).delay(1500); 
});
```

or even more betterer (then i'm done, I promise)

```
$screenHeader.children().each(function () {
  $screenHeader.queue(function () {
    $(this).addClass('visible');
    $screenHeader.dequeue();
  }).delay(1500); 
});
```

Now, I know there's some funkiness with how $(this) is passed around so that last one isn't a priority, but it would be really nice to get some sort of loop working. Listing them out and repeating all that code and being tied to the html kills me.

Help would be greatly appreciated.  :)

Comment: Did you find any of the below answers helpful, or do you need more help?

Comment: Hey @mjswensen! First, thank you for your thorough answer. I did find the answers helpful, but I still feel like they're both skirting the issue of why it doesn't work in one of the ways I imagine it should, or how to do it using jQuery queue.  I also like the cleanliness of simply adding a class and having it transition automatically as opposed to adding a delay.  I'm also using this multiple times on different "headers" within the same page, so I need to be able to trigger the animation programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

`$(this)` inside the `$screenHeader.queue(...` loop was the header.  I needed to store the child before entering the loop queue part.

```
var delayTime = 1500,
    $screenHeader = $('#screen-'+screenIndex+' header'),
    $copyChildren = $screenHeader.children('.copy');

$copyChildren.each(function () {
  var child = $(this);
  $screenHeader.queue(function () {
    child.addClass('visible');
    $screenHeader.dequeue();
  }).delay(delayTime); 
});
```

Feelin classy.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do like this:

```
var $elements = $('header').find('.copy');
$($elements).each(function(i, ui){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(ui).addClass('visible');
    },(i*1500));
});
```

Comment: I didn't want to use setTimeout.  I feel its a bit hacky and insecure.  I wanted to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using CSS for the timing of the animation, instead of jQuery.

See [this live example](http://codepen.io/mjswensen/pen/gbZejV).

And here is the code:

HTML:

```
<header>
  <p class="copy">Thing one</p>
  <p class="copy">Thing two</p>
  <p class="copy">Cat in the Hat</p>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes fade-in {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

header p {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fade-in;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('header').children().each(function(idx) {
    $(this).css('animation-delay', idx * 500 + 'ms')
  });
});
```

In my solution, I am using jQuery only for the "arbitrary number of children" part of your question. If you knew the number of children in advance (or, at least had an idea as to what the maximum number of children might ever be), you could do the animation entirely in CSS:

```
header p:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 500ms; }
header p:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 1s; }
/* So on and so forth until your bases are covered... */
```

(That type of solution would be very easy to generate in a loop using a CSS preprocessor like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) or [Less](http://lesscss.org).)